# How do I send e-mail out through a specific IP?

Tags: email, iptables, nat

We have 3 IPs hooked to a single interface. I'd like e-mail traffic to go out through a specific IP, which is not the default one. (This is because we keep getting blocked by Spamhaus so I want to separate the e-mail traffic from, e.g., outbound wi-fi traffic.)

The existing block of iptables rules looks like this:

```
#Email
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 25
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp3s0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to [server's LAN IP]:25
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 110
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp3s0 -p tcp --dport 110 -j DNAT --to [server's LAN IP]:110
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 143
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp3s0 -p tcp --dport 143 -j DNAT --to [server's LAN IP]:143
```

`enp3s0` is the external NIC, the internal NIC is `enp6s0` if it matters.

What can I add / modify to this to make outbound traffic go through the non-default specific IP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `iptables` and change the source IP in the `POSTROUTING` chain of the `nat` table or use advanced routing with `ip rule` and create an additional routing table in which you set the address for the `src` attribute.

### iptables

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING \
    -o "$wan_if" -p tcp --dport 25 -j SNAT --to-source "$mail_ip"
```

### policy routing

```
# just once
echo '25    smtp' >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables

# after each boot
ip route add "$next_hop_network" dev "$wan_if"
ip route add default via "$next_hop" src "$mail_ip" table smtp
ip rule add prio 100 ipproto tcp dport 25 lookup smtp
```

Comment: Thanks! First way didn't work, trying second way. What is $next_hop meant to be? I get an error "Error: ??? address is expected rather than "[IP address I want to use]""

Comment: Strange, `iptables` should work. `$next_hop` is your default gateway, the IP in the output of `ip r | grep default`.